# Is there English proverb or saying equivalent to Chinese / Japanese common proverb 李下に冠を正さず- Don’t touch (redress) your coronet under the plum tree?

Tags: proverbs

Recently I made an inadvertent  mistake, which reminded me a familiar Japanese proverb to admonish us to stay away from situation and the likelihood to be suspected as a rule-offender.
It is a set of words, 李下に冠を正さず - Don’t touch your coronet under the plum tree, and瓜田に靴を入れずDon’t wear shoes in cucurbit field, lest you should be suspected as a cucurbit or plum fruit thief.

I understand the proverb came from the passage, 君子防未然。不処嫌疑間。瓜田不納履、李下不正冠 that can be translated as “Gentlemen prevent problems in advance.  Don’t wear shoes in cucurbit field. Don’t touch your coronet under the plum tree,” in君子行 (Gentleman’s Conduct) in Chinese classic literature,古楽府.

We also have a proverb, 転ばぬ先の杖 – Walk with a stick before you stumble (on stone) referring to preparedness, but it’s different from李下に冠を正さず in meaning.

Are there similar English proverbs or maxims as李下に冠を正さずthat admonish us to keep away from the habit, or taking action to get involved in the unexpected problem or disaster as a result? I would like to tell it to myself.

Comment: Not sure why the shoes or the coronet, but the general idea of your question is clear. (Some English speakers might not be familiar with the word *cucurbit*, which means any plant in family Cucurbitaceae, the cucumber family.) I can't think of English proverbs about being prepared or avoiding being mistaken for a thief. Hopefully someone else can.

Comment: @Drew.I picked up 'cucurbit" as a translation for 瓜 ( pronounced gua in Chinese, and ka or uri in Japanese) in Kenkyusha’s Japanese English Dictionary. But Koseikan’s Modern Chinese Japanese Dictionary defines 瓜 as the generic term of water melon, pumpkin, cucumber and the like. I think sweet water melon would be suitable to the story.

Comment: Somehow, I was thinking about [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPJZTRqQ1Xw) when I saw this question.

Comment: @Drew If you reach up (to your head, to touch your coronet) when you're under a plumb tree, it might look like you're reaching up to steal plums.

Comment: I have found one proverb in my dictionary about plum thieves, but the moral is different: *When a knave is in a plum-tree, he has neither friend nor kin.*

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the original proverbs. Why would wearing shoes in the cucurbit field make you look like a thief?

Comment: @Starsplusplus. In ancient time, farmers who raise crops, vegetables, and fruits worked barefoot in the field. You see barefoot villagers in outlands in any corners of the world even today. If they find someone wearing shoes (which is unusual on the farm) steps into their watermelon patch, he will be suspected as a stranger who is going to steal watermelons by the owner of the farm and villagers.

Comment: On some level I feel like even if there is an equivalent saying it isn't very common here in the US, possibly because this sentiment is somewhat counter to our cultural assumptions, e.g. innocent until proven guilty, it's a free country, etc. "Why should I care what they think? I'm not stealing anything."

Comment: @starsplusplus Maybe it means bending to wear the shoes. That could be mistaken for bending down to pick up the vegetables.

Comment: @algiogia Why are you speculating when Yoichi's already told us the reason? Wearing the shoes in the field marks you as an outsider, which in turn makes people think you are only there to steal.

Comment: @stars Actually, algiogia’s speculation is more accurate than Yoichi’s explanation. In the original Classical Chinese text, 納 refers to putting on the shoes, rather than just wearing them. This also makes the parallel to 正 adjusting (rather than just wearing) the hat more exact.

Comment: @starsplusplus google translates 入れ as "put", so I wonder whether the passage means to have already the shoes on or to put them on. I don't speak Japanese so I cannot confirm. The former case implies you are near the "thief" to notice he has shoes, while in the latter you can mistake him from a distance.

Comment: @algiogia The Japanese form 入れず _irezu_ is indeed the (old-fashioned) negative imperative of 入れる _ireru_ ‘put’ (the transitive counterpart to intransitive 入る _iru_ ‘enter, go into’). Wearing shoes is more commonly expressed by the verb 履く _haku_, which refers specifically to wearing items of clothing on the lower part of the body (shoes, trousers), so 瓜田に靴を履かず would be “don’t wear shoes…”.

Comment: Maybe "Don't tie up your shoes in a melon field" is better understood by native English speakers.

Comment: 瓜田に履を納れず
http://kotowaza-allguide.com/ka/kadennikutsu.html

Comment: I can't find it anywhere, but a teacher once advised us to cite the sources we used for help on our homework with the saying "Stay on the lighter shade of gray." (He attributed the quote to NM Rep. Heather Wilson.) The thinking was, "If not citing sources makes you look like a plagiarist, why not take the small trouble to cite?" This is probably more like "If you're going to adjust your hat under the tree, don't do it directly beneath a plum." But it is still similar in the sense of taking steps not to be viewed as a rule-offender.

Comment: This question is terminally unclear. Shouldn't the question be put on hold until it is optimally written for everyone to understand? From my point of view it appears to be slanted towards Japanese when this is an English website. Perhaps the originator would have greater success at Linguistics SE.

Comment: The question asks about an English proverb(which corresponds to a Japanese one). I think it's better suited for ELL because native English speakers can easily answer it. It's an interesting question in that it reminds us people are alike all over, but it's beside the site's scope.

Comment: @ivanhoescott I used to post this kind of questions in here, not because I'm fluent in English but because I'm not in need of learning English. I just wonder `English language enthusiasts'` opinions because I'm a enthusiast in my language.

Comment: @9dan A question most native English speakers can easily answer is off-topic in this site. I think asking about an English proverb is such a question.

Comment: I don't think anyone else has addressed this directly: the translation into English of 'coronet' and 'curcurbit' are very strange. 'coronet' is a rarer word for 'crown', and it sounds very strange to be wearing either in a field or to worry about reaching up to touch it. 'curcurbit' may very well be soething like a cucumber but I've never heard the word before, and it sticks out like a sore thumb, so much so that it renders the proverb empty. It sounds like a google translation (where a random synonym is taken instead of the most appropriate one..

Comment: ＠Mitch. You are right. I made a literal translation of Japanese (and Chinese) characters of both 冠 and 瓜田 by referring to Japanese English Dictionary published by Kenkyusha Publishing, which provided 'coronet' and ‘curcurbit' as the English counterparts to 冠 and 瓜田. But in second thought, both translations don’t fit the actual meanings of the original words. 冠 is something like a white derby used to be worn by gentlemen outside the house, and 瓜田 is melon field or plantation. 哈密瓜 – melons produced in Xinjiang Uygur region of China is famous for its deliciousness and sweetness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of any exactly like yours. There are lots of idioms about being careful or avoiding obviously unwise situations, some of them are:

> - "Better safe than sorry." (be careful not to take unnecessary risks)
> - "Look before you leap." (be careful not to hurry and in your haste make a bad decision)
> - "Don't spit into the wind." (also *piss*) (Don't do something that has a very good chance of turning out badly for you)

Comment: And you [don't pull the mask off the old Lone Ranger
and you don't mess around with Jim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Don%27t_Mess_Around_with_Jim_%28song%29).  Probably one of the best cultural references, although probably not so well known to younger people.

Comment: I don't think there's a real equivalent, but these seem pretty close. Another one might be "don't play with matches/fire".

Comment: “Don't piss into the wind” is often(ish) quoted in its Latin form, which is closer to the Japanese proverb: _vir prudens non contra ventum mingit_ ‘a wise man does not piss against the wind’. A decent fit, though it lacks the element of suspicion or ill deeds of its Japanese counterpart.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet If you take out the "element of suspicion or ill deeds" then what's left? I thought that what we're looking for is, "A proverb which recommends avoiding an action which would result in a suspicion of ill deeds."

Comment: @ChrisW What’s left is “a proverb which recommends avoiding an action which would result in something unpleasant or unwanted for the actor himself”, which is more or less the same thing, only at a more generic level. Since consensus here seems to be that an exact match on all levels is not likely to be found, I’d say this is probably as close as you can get. Whether it will be a useful substitute in practice will depend on the specific context and the relative importance of the suspected ill deeds in it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you, I understand now why that's seen as a potential match.

Comment: @HotLicks You missed "don't tug on Superman's cape" :-) Thanks for the link. I had no idea that song had it's own page on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Tonny - Doesn't everything?

Answer (score 25):

I'm going to suggest you to ***remain above suspicion***.

Because, the main idea in your question is "don't do things that can make you look suspicious".

The idiom "above suspicion" comes from Caesar's famous statement about his wife:

> *Caesar's wife must be above suspicion.*

---

> <sub>*above suspicion* - [for one] to be honest enough that no one would suspect one; in a position where one could not be suspected.
>   (*Typically: be ~; keep oneself ~; remain ~.)</sub>

<sub><sup>Dictionary Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/suspicioning</sup></sub>

Comment: To support my answer: On a website, it is mentioned as a moral of the story by a rabbi regarding to a concern about arousing suspicion of shoplifting. Source: http://ohr.edu/3571

Comment: The idiom is: *to BE* [above suspicion](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Above+Suspicion) We don't normally say:  "remain above suspicion". The meaning doesn't change, it's similar to being irreproachable.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I say. "Remain" is a better verb if you are suggesting it to someone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes I mentioned that in Caesar's statement. I just didn't want to iterate again. "Above suspicion" is an idiom itself too. But it is usually used with _be_ or _remain_. "Remain" has a more prevalent usage than "stay". Also, "be","remain" and "keep yourself" are mentioned in TFD.

Comment: That is idiomatic but not a proverb.

Comment: @denten: OP asked for a proverb or _saying_. Not only for a proverb. You can consider this phrase as an idiomatic saying. As there isn't a well-established proverb for this concept, this expression fits well.

Answer (score 23):

People should not only avoid [impropriety](https://www.google.com/search?q=impropriety) but also **avoid even the [Appearance of impropriety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appearance_of_impropriety)**.

Comment: Although not as poetic as the fable described in the question, I think this is the closest translation which would be widely understood.

Comment: Yes, it's not a "proverb" at all. It's a ... I don't know what you'd call it: an "idiom" or "jargon" or a "well-known phrase".

Answer (score 13):

With regard to the conclusion that one should stay away from situations that may mark one as a rule breaker even if one is innocent, I am reminded not of any particular English proverb, but of Aesop's fable of the [farmer and the stork](http://mythfolklore.net/aesopica/milowinter/21.htm). The book *Aesop for Children*, which my parents used to read to me and my siblings when we were young, tells the story this way:

> THE FARMER AND THE STORK
>
> A Stork of a very simple and trusting nature had been asked by a gay party of Cranes to visit a field that had been newly planted. But the party ended dismally with all the birds entangled in the meshes of the Farmer's net.
>
> The Stork begged the Farmer to spare him.
>
> "Please let me go," he pleaded. "I belong to the Stork family who you know are honest and birds of good character. Besides, I did not know the Cranes were going to steal."
>
> "You may be a very good bird," answered the Farmer, "but I caught you with the thieving Cranes and you will have to share the same punishment with them."
>
> *Moral: You are judged by the company you keep.*

The poignancy of this story is increased by the fact that, whereas cranes love to eat grain (and other seeds), as well as small animals, storks much prefer a diet of fish, frogs, insects, mice, etc.; so the stork could hardly have done any damage to the farmer's crop by associating with the cranes. But the farmer either didn't know that fact or didn't care.

By the way, the moral that the anonymous author of *Aesop for Children* drew from this fable is not Aesop's; an equally valid conclusion might be *When you are caught in a compromising situation, appearances may count for more than actual intentions.*

Comment: It was a year ago, September / 
a day I well remember /
I was walking up and down / 
in drunken pride /
when my knees began to flutter / 
and I fell down in the gutter /
and a pig came by and lay down by my side /
 
As I lay there in the gutter /
thinking thoughts I could not utter /
I thought I heard a passing lady say, /
"You can tell a man who boozes /
by the company he chooses..." /
And with that, the pig got up and walked away.

Comment: What a horrible farmer person.

Comment: @Sven Yargs. "Farmer and the crane" allegory is interesting. But weighing with alternatives suggested by Medica and Mari-LouA, I thought Medica's ones (Look before you leap and Don't spit into the wind) looked closer to the original concept, “Gentlemen prevent problems in advance." I wonder I can rephrase "spit" in “Don't spit intto the wind" with "piss," which sounds more humorous.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: I agree with your reasoning. I'm familiar with the expression "Don't [or "Never"] piss into the wind" as homespun advice; and I think that a lot of other people in the United States have used or heard that saying, too. Moreover, it—like Erik Kowal's suggestions and medica's other nominees—is a lot closer to a proverb (which is what you asked for) than is the fable I suggested.

Comment: @NeilKirk: German has "mitgefangen, mitgehangen" -- you get caught with them, you get hanged with them.

Answer (score 11):

It'll probably never rise to the status of a saying, but good advice nonetheless:

> "Never pick your nose at an auction!"

Comment: Sound advice. I've been in that exact situation. Lucky for me 2 other guys started a bidding war after my accidental bid. No idea what I would have done with a pallet of chain-saws.

Comment: But this definitely should be a saying. I will certainly start using it :)

Answer (score 8):

> "Lie down with dogs, wake up with fleas".
>
> "A man is known by the company he keeps".
>
> "Never trouble trouble till trouble troubles you".
>
> "The rotten apple spoils its neighbours".

Comment: I don't really think they are relevant, unless I've seriously mistaken the question.

Comment: @Lohoris - I think you've mistaken the question. The OP said (and here I paraphrase) that he recalled certain Japanese proverbs warning one to stay away from situations and circumstances where one might be suspected of committing an offence of some kind. I put it to you that keeping bad company and muckraking or meddling exemplify this type of situation.

Comment: Yes but those you list mean "don't hang out with bad people". The meaning he was searching instead was "don't do things that might be mistaken as suspicious". So your is a very strict and small subset of the one requested.

Comment: @Lohoris - If I'd been able to identify some proverbs that explicitly conveyed the precise meaning you have cited, I would certainly have included them. But I don't believe there are any: if you disagree, see if you can do any better. I will be the first to upvote any that match your criteria. :)

Comment: I guess @ermanen's post is as good as we can get here.

Comment: I suppose it is; but even his suggestion ("Caesar's wife must be above suspicion") doesn't quite cut it, because the underlying meaning of that saying is "People in positions of power or prominence have a particular duty to behave in an exemplary manner". In other words, it's not a *general* warning to avoid being caught in circumstances that might lead others to suspect you of having done something underhand, which is the connotation the questioner was hoping to find expressed in the proverbs suggested in the answers.

Comment: @ErikKowal: General warning that I gave as an answer is "remain above suspicion". It covers the situation well. "Caesar's wife must be above suspicion" can be used in certain situations and I mentioned that because "above suspicion" is originated from there.

Comment: @ermanen - OK, but the OP was asking for a *proverb or maxim*;  the phrase 'remain above suspicion' is only a collocation.

Comment: @ErikKowal: Idioms are considered as a "saying" too. You can call it an idiomatic saying also. Instead of giving a distant proverb as an answer, it is better to give an exact idiomatic saying.

Answer (score 6):

"Abstain from all appearance of evil."
[1 Thessalonians 5:22](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Th&c=5&p=0&rl=0&ss=0&t=KJV)

"But take heed lest by any means this liberty of yours become a stumblingblock"
[1 Corinthians 8:9](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=1Co&c=8&p=0&rl=0&ss=0&t=KJV)

These verses are often interpreted [(a)](http://www.gotquestions.org/appearance-of-evil.html) [(b)](http://www.godvine.com/bible/1-thessalonians/5-22) [(c)](http://www.apologeticspress.org/apcontent.aspx?category=11&article=437) [(d)](http://www.padfield.com/1996/appear.html) [(e)](http://www.awmi.net/bible/1co_08_09) [(f)](http://www.letgodbetrue.com/sermons/church/christian-liberty/sermon.php) as a recommendation to try to avoid actions and situations that, while technically not crossing over the line into wrong-doing, come so close enough to that line that others suspect you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Another similar and common idiom is the idea, common in Jewish scholarship, but also seen elsewhere, of a *fence around the law*. As in, going beyond the most basic requirements of the rules, to ensure that you don't fall afoul of them by skirting too close. The classic example is, that while Jewish law merely restricts the *use* of tools (such as a pencil) to perform work (such as writing) on the sabbath, many Jews will refrain from even *handling* such tools, lest they give the wrong impression, or, worse yet, forget the restriction and begin to use them (I.e. idly doodling).

Answer (score 4):

"Avoid the very appearance of evil" is widely used in this sense.  I would have wagered that it was the King James Version (Authorized Version) translation of the Greek original, but it seems "Abstain from all appearance of evil" is what the KJV actually says.  At any rate the "Avoid..." form is what I've generally seen and heard.  Google turned up over 32,000 instances in a quick search.

Comment: You might also want to search for the expression "Honi soit qui mal y pense".  It is the mirror image of the expression you're seeking.  It is usually translated "Evil to him who thinks evil" or loosely "How dare you assume I'm stealing your fruit because I adjusted my hat!"

Answer (score 2):

Some common idioms and one proverb which warn against acting on impulse

- *Don't say or do anything [you might regret later](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regret)*
- *Don't say/do anything which might show/paint/put you* [*in a bad light*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/show-someone-in-a-bad-light).
- [*Think twice*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/think+twice) before speaking (or) *before you act*.
- *Fools rush in where angels fear to tread*

> **Proverb**: A person who does not plan ahead and think matters through becomes
>   involved in risky or unfavorable situations which prudent people
>   avoid.  Often abbreviated as **fools rush in**

[Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fools_rush_in_where_angels_fear_to_tread)

Answer (score 2):

I feel like the old "If it looks/walks/quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck" might be applicable here.

Answer (score 2):

We have some that are similar in a way, but the ones that are well known (at least to me) come out of urban or bureaucratic culture rather than agrarian culture. We probably have some older agrarians ones that I'm not aware of. Some examples...

For avoiding accusations of wrongdoing, mistakes, legal penalties:
"Cover your ass." Abbreviated CYA when it is not acceptable to pronounce the word "ass."

The above is similar in the sense that it arises out of the same desire to avoid being accused. The possibly related phrase "don't show your ass" is used to warn someone not to behave in a way that makes them seem "low-class."

For avoiding the perception that you belong to a lower social order:
"You can tell a person by the company they keep." Or more poetically, "you can tell a man who boozes by the company he chooses."

Perhaps the above is related to the sayings you mentioned, since your sayings seem to be about nobility or merchant class folk who are trying not to be confused with drifters, drunks, highwaymen, or petty thieves.

Comment: For completeness, the phrase "you can tell a man who boozes by the company he chooses" goes back at least as far as 1933, when it was part of the song "The Pig Got Up and Slowly Walked Away. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pig_Got_Up_and_Slowly_Walked_Away It may have (probably did?) existed in that form before that.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few more proverbs/idioms which are somewhat similar to yours in meaning.

As for the meaning of preparedness in your proverb: *A stitch in time saves nine* refers to sewing. A garment might have a small tear, if you're able to repair it soon enough, it will save you more stitches (trouble) in the future.

For the meaning of not doing something risky or there will be bad consequences in your proverb: The expression *play with fire and you'll get burned* is pretty straightforward.

And finally, if you don't want to stick out in the watermelon patch because you're wearing shoes, we also have a proverb which is quite close to this meaning: *When in Rome, do as the Romans.* This is usually said to someone to warn them not to draw undue attention to themselves or to simply tell them to try and fit in and things should work out better for them. It's also used by someone who is trying to explain their unusual actions to a fellow compatriot in a foreign situation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a saying that is similar to the meaning but different in tense **"Caught in the wrong place at the wrong time"**. It usually means someone is simply near a crime scene and despite the fact that they are innocent, they manage to look guilty, for example...

Alice has been brutally murdered, and her husband Bob, was seen walking out of the building with a meat cleaver. He got arrested on suspicion, but he was just going to the knife shop to get his cleaver sharpened!

Comment: He was actually gonna kill her after he sharpened it, but someone beat him to it.

Answer (score 0):

[*Don't do the crime if you can't do the time*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Don't+do+the+crime%2C+if+you+can't+do+the+time.) is the closest expression I can think of.  ("Doing time" means spending time in prison.)

However, it is not equivalent to your expression.  "Don't do the crime…" warns of real consequences for wrongdoing, whereas 瓜田李下 (roughly summarized as "Tying your shoes in a melon patch") warns about false accusations that are likely to be made based on suspicious-looking activity.

Instead of a proverb, I'd simply say: **Avoid suspicion** or **Be [beyond reproach](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=beyond+reproach).**

Answer (score 0):

'Ceasar's wife' sounds like the closest of all these suggestions, but it lacks the imperative 'admonishing' quality of the originals. I suggest we adopt them into English: 'Don't straighten your hat under a plum tree' and 'Don't wear track shoes into a melon patch'.

Answer (score 0):

***Never piss in another man's soup*** is my personal generic favourite at the moment.

Distasteful, but exceedingly accurate in your instance is ***Never wear an Anorak to a playground.***